# Access parent FlatList data inside child FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am rendering multiple `FlatList` children inside a parent `FlatList` like so

```
<FlatList
    data={parenttypes}
    renderItem={({item})=><View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={childtypes}
                renderItem={({item})=><View>
                    <Text>HOW DO I ACCESS PARENT'S item here as well</Text>
                </View>}
            />      
    </View>}
/>
```

How can I access parent `FlatList`'s `item` inside child `FlatList`?

Comment: Don't use destructuring in the inner function, and instead just put a different parameter name: `(otherItem) => ...` then you can reference the enclosing `item`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple solution is, instead of using arrow function for child `FlatList`, create separate function and bind the parent data inside child callback method.

Like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={parenttypes}
    renderItem={({item})=><View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={childtypes}
                renderItem={this._renderChildItem.bind(this, item)}
            />      
    </View>}
/>

_renderChildItem(parentData, {item}) {
    console.log('data', parentData, item);
    return (    
        <View>
            <Text>HOW DO I ACCESS PARENT'S item here as well</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Not sure but try this one also:

```
<FlatList
    data={parenttypes}
    renderItem={({item}) => { 
        let parentData = item;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={childtypes}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        console.log('data', parentData, item);
                        return(
                            <View>
                                <Text>HOW DO I ACCESS PARENT'S item here as well</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    }
                />      
            </View>
        )
    }
/>
```

Comment: I followed the second approach. Kudos!!